# Saber cuantas filas se insertaron en una consulta

Tags: sql, plsql, trigger, oracle-11g

Necesito saber el número de filas que se insertaron en una consulta PL/SQL.

Es decir, si en mi consulta agregué 9 registros, el resultado final sería el número 9.

Pensé quizás con un

```
SELECT COUNT(:NEW:INGRESADOS) FROM LOGS;
```

O algo por el estilo, pero no sé muy bien como implementarlo. Estoy trabajando con disparos (TRIGGER), en sql oracle 11g, PL/SQL

Answer (score 2):

El número de filas insertadas con una sentencia INSERT o borradas con un DELETE se obtiene con la siguiente variable:

```
sql%rowcount
```